# Hiding the identity of a party within the Kerberos authentication scheme

Tags: keys, symmetric, key-exchange, key-reuse, kerberos

In the Kerberos authentication protocol, as described [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.99.2838&rep=rep1&type=pdf#page=517):

[image: kerberos]

would it be safer to replace step (1) with:

$$
A \rightarrow T : A, E_{K_A{_{T}}}(B, N_A) 
$$

so that a passive adversary does not know the identity of party B with which A wishes to communicate?

Or even add an extra layer of security by encrypting the whole message with a globally distributed symmetric key:

$$ 
K_G
$$
thus message (1) becoming:
$$
A \rightarrow T : E_{K_G}(A, B, N_A) 
$$

where KG is a global key shared with all potential clients, and the trusted third party T decrypts any incoming request with this key; it assumes that all inbound ciphertexts are initially encrypted once with the respective key.

Comment: Good question. I have no answer, but improving privacy is always a good thing. Therefore, thumbs up!